# Apply correct dimens file for Samsung S8

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to design a widget and you might know, this is a lot of fun. :)
I think I figured it out for most of the devices, but now I have a Samsung Galaxy S8.

I thought it should use the dimens from my xxxhdpi (regarding to the resolution) folder, but it doesn't. It uses `sw400dp-xxhdpi`. But the dimens for `sw400dp-xxhdpi` devices does not fit for the S8.

Regarding to the specs it has 360x740dp. So I tried `360x740/dimens.xml` and  `h740dp/dimens.xml` none of them are working. It still uses `sw400dp`.

I might need some other dimens.xml files, is there any easy way to see which device will use which file?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because your math is wrong.  The S8 is 2,960×1,440 at 568 dpi.  1440/568*160=405.  So its width is greater than 400.  Its grabbing the right file.  I'm not sure where you got 360 from.

Edit:  Were you using the multiplier for your math(1x,2x,3x, etc)?  Don't.  The actual DPI values are used most of the time.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I didn't meant to use `sw400` for the S8. 
`360x740dp` are taken from https://material.io/tools/devices/ (WidthxHeight). I'm still not really sure which applier I should use now for this device. `sw405`? Seems kinda strange.

Comment: @chrjs I question why you need to specify different files for every device. Most apps use one size, or 3 (phone, small tablet, large tablet) at most. Using device specific ones usually means you're not using the right techniques for scaling.

Comment: As for the site you posted- they're using the scaling factor and dividing by 4. Which is wrong, and will lead to mistakes like this. The scaling factor is an estimate you can use for a short length, like a padding between two elements, not for something large.

Comment: I don't want to. I didn't do it before. But with Widgets it seems kinda necessary, because the widgets looks different on most different configurations. So at least I try to cover most of the dimensions.

Comment: @chrsj not knowing what you're doing I can't point to specific fixers. I can say that I've done android since 2010 and never once made a phone specific layout file

Comment: `sw405` works for now. But I will try to figure out why my widget design seems to be messed up a bit. Thanks!